# Unexplained behaviour of python logging in spyder that differs from command-line interpreter

Tags: python, logging, spyder

I am really struggling with Python's [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) library, which seems so promising. This is perhaps in part because I typically use Spyder IDE.

To start, I don't entirely understand the differences between running Python from within Spyder IDE vs running from a command-line interpreter, but I think I understand enough to know that running in Spyder will keep my session open such that by repeatedly running a script with the logging standard library, this can result in additional handlers continuing to be added to previously established loggers.  It's irritating, but manageable.

But this really has me baffled. If I run the code below in a command-line interpreter, it will produce output that I expect (summarized here):

- No loggers exist at start of program
- One is created, info is logged to screen from within setup_logger()
- info is also logged to screen from within main()
- 1 logger exists at end of program

```
# my_log.py

import logging

_log_format = '''My format | %(name)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s'''

def setup_logger(name):

    print()
    print('Setting up loggers...')

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    sh = logging.StreamHandler()
    sh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    sh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(_log_format))
    logger.addHandler(sh)

    logger.info('''Info logged from within setup_logger''' \
                ' *** but not in spyder, instead it gets logged to screen before anything else ***''')

    print('... done setting up loggers')
    print()

    return logger

def main():

    logger.info('Info logged from within main' \
                ' *** but not in spyder, instead it gets logged to screen before anything else ***''')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    loggers = [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
    print('Start of program, there are {} loggers (expected 0)'.format(len(loggers)))
    print('List of loggers:', loggers)

    logger = setup_logger(__name__)

    main()

    loggers = [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
    print('End of program, there are {} loggers (expected 1)'.format(len(loggers)))
    print('List of loggers:', loggers)
```

However, if I run this code in Spyder, I get this instead:

- *** Info from both setup_logger() and main() is logged to screen immediately, before I expect to have any logger setup! ***
- then it prints that 18 loggers exist at start of program (spyder loggers... weird, but ok)
- prints that it is setting up loggers, but nothing gets logged here... it already was previously
- end of program, there are now 19 loggers, so my logger was added to the 18 spyder loggers

Here is the command-line and expected output:

```
List of loggers: []

Setting up loggers...
My format | __main__ | INFO | Info logged from within setup_logger *** but not in spyder, instead it gets logged to screen before anything else ***
... done setting up loggers

My format | __main__ | INFO | Info logged from within main *** but not in spyder, instead it gets logged to screen before anything else ***
End of program, there are 1 loggers (expected 1)
List of loggers: [<Logger __main__ (DEBUG)>]
```

Here is the Spyder and unexpected output:

```
My format | __main__ | INFO | Info logged from within setup_logger *** but not in spyder, instead it gets logged to screen before anything else ***
My format | __main__ | INFO | Info logged from within main *** but not in spyder, instead it gets logged to screen before anything else ***
Start of program, there are 18 loggers (expected 0)
List of loggers: [<Logger concurrent.futures (WARNING)>, <Logger concurrent (WARNING)>, <Logger asyncio (WARNING)>, <Logger parso.python.diff (WARNING)>, <Logger parso.python (WARNING)>, <Logger parso (WARNING)>, <Logger parso.cache (WARNING)>, <Logger spyder_kernels.comms.commbase (WARNING)>, <Logger spyder_kernels.comms (WARNING)>, <Logger spyder_kernels (WARNING)>, <Logger tornado.access (WARNING)>, <Logger tornado (WARNING)>, <Logger tornado.application (WARNING)>, <Logger tornado.general (WARNING)>, <Logger spyder_kernels.customize.spyderpdb (WARNING)>, <Logger spyder_kernels.customize (WARNING)>, <Logger spydercustomize (WARNING)>, <Logger SpyderKernelApp (WARNING)>]

Setting up loggers...
done setting up loggers

End of program, there are 19 loggers (expected 1)
List of loggers: [<Logger concurrent.futures (WARNING)>, <Logger concurrent (WARNING)>, <Logger asyncio (WARNING)>, <Logger parso.python.diff (WARNING)>, <Logger parso.python (WARNING)>, <Logger parso (WARNING)>, <Logger parso.cache (WARNING)>, <Logger spyder_kernels.comms.commbase (WARNING)>, <Logger spyder_kernels.comms (WARNING)>, <Logger spyder_kernels (WARNING)>, <Logger tornado.access (WARNING)>, <Logger tornado (WARNING)>, <Logger tornado.application (WARNING)>, <Logger tornado.general (WARNING)>, <Logger spyder_kernels.customize.spyderpdb (WARNING)>, <Logger spyder_kernels.customize (WARNING)>, <Logger spydercustomize (WARNING)>, <Logger SpyderKernelApp (WARNING)>, <Logger __main__ (DEBUG)>]
```

Can anyone shed light on why this is happening and how (if possible) I can fix it within Spyder?

### EDIT:

Maybe this is a hint, if I walk through in debug mode in Spyder, it works fine... is print just slower than logging, is it that easy? Am I just slower than a smart person?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) The kernel (which is the external process that runs your code in Spyder) is a not a simple Python interpreter but a small library (called `spyder_kernels`) that depends on several others (such as `ipykernel` and `wurlitzer`), which in turn depend on more libraries (such as `tornado` and `IPython`). It seems several of them register loggers when they are imported.

Comment: If you want to develop in Spyder and have the running experience of a regular Python interpreter, please go to the menu `Run > Configuration per file` and select the options `Execute in an external system terminal` and `Interact with the Python console after execution`.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba This is interesting, thanks for the info on Spyder's kernel and the tip on running in the external system terminal, this is a good workaround.